# Creating hash from array adding new keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array looking like this:

```
data =[[01, 777], [02, 888]]
```

Now I want to create a hash from it like below:

```
n_clip = [{"name"=>"01", "rep"=>"777"},{"name"=>"02", rep=>"888"}]
```

I tried to do this in that way:

```
n_clip = []
data.each do |a|
n_clip << Array[Hash[a.map {|| ["name", a.first]}], Hash[a.map {|| ["rep", a.last]}]]
end
```

but it doesn't work because I get:

```
n_clip = [[{"name"=>"01"},{"rep"="777"}], [{"name"=>"01"},{"rep"="777"}]]
```

and definitively it isn't what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.map { |arr| { 'name' => arr[0], 'rep' => arr[1] } }
```

i would rather use symbols as hash keys

```
data.map { |arr| { name: arr[0], rep: arr[1] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create an array of two hashes, each having the same two keys, the other answers are fine. The following handles the case where there are an arbitrary number of keys and `data` may contain an arbitrary number of elements.

```
def hashify(keys, arr_of_vals)
  [keys].product(arr_of_vals).map { |ak,av| Hash[ak.zip(av)] }
end

keys = %w| name rep |
  #=> ["name", "rep"] 
arr_of_vals = [["01", "777"], ["02", "888"]]
hashify(keys, arr_of_vals)
  #=> [{"name"=>"01", "rep"=>"777"}, {"name"=>"02", "rep"=>"888"}]
```

In your problem `arr_of_vals` must first be derived from `[[1, 777], [02, 888]]`, but that is a secondary (rather mundane) problem that I will not address.

Another example:

```
keys = %w| name rep group |
  #=> ["name", "rep", "group"] 
arr_of_vals = [[1, 777, 51], [2, 888, 52], [1, 2, 53], [3, 4, 54]]
hashify(keys, arr_of_vals)
  #=> [{"name"=>1, "rep"=>777, "group"=>51}, {"name"=>2, "rep"=>888, "group"=>52},
  #    {"name"=>1, "rep"=>2, "group"=>53}, {"name"=>3, "rep"=>4, "group"=>54}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.map { |name, rep| { 'name' => name.to_s, 'rep' => rep.to_s } }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.